# Enable hardware acceleration for swf generated in Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, hardware-acceleration

Is it possible to enable hardware acceleration (Level 1, Level 2) for a swf generated in Flash Builder. I don´t use the Flash IDE and therefor I have no access to the "Publish Settings" in the Flash IDE? Maybe there is som compiler arguments?

[image]

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7bcea.html

> To enable the SWF file to use hardware acceleration, select one of the
>   following options from the Hardware Acceleration menu: Level 1 -
>   Direct Direct mode improves playback performance by allowing Flash
>   Player to draw directly on the screen instead of letting the browser
>   do the drawing. Level 2 - GPU In GPU mode, Flash Player utilizes the
>   available computing power of the graphics card to perform video
>   playback and compositing of layered graphics. This provides another
>   level of performance benefit depending on the user's graphics
>   hardware. Use this option when you expect that your audience will have
>   high-end graphics cards. If the playback system does not have
>   sufficient hardware to enable acceleration, Flash Player reverts to
>   normal drawing mode automatically. For best performance on web pages
>   containing multiple SWF files, enable hardware acceleration for only
>   one of the SWF files. Hardware acceleration is not used in Test Movie
>   mode. When you publish your SWF file, the HTML file that embeds it
>   contains a wmode HTML parameter. Choosing Level 1 or Level 2 hardware
>   acceleration sets the wmode HTML parameter to "direct" or "gpu"
>   respectively. Turning on hardware acceleration overrides the Window
>   Mode setting you may have chosen in the HTML tab of the Publish
>   Settings dialog box, because it is also stored in the wmode parameter
>   in the HTML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When you publish your SWF file, the HTML file that embeds it contains a wmode HTML parameter. Choosing Level 1 or Level 2 hardware acceleration sets the wmode HTML parameter to "direct" or "gpu" respectively. Turning on hardware acceleration overrides the Window Mode setting you may have chosen in the HTML tab of the Publish Settings dialog box

So it's my understanding that you just need to set the wmode parameter in your html, no need for any compiler options.

This link explains things in a bit more detail:
http://labs.almerblank.com/2011/03/the-wmode-embed-parameter-de-mystified/

Comment: So the html parameter overrides the Flash Publish settings? Not the other way around?

Comment: It's been a while since I used the Flash IDE and I'm not near a copy at the moment so I can't check but as far as I'm aware the Publish settings are doing exactly that: setting the HTML parameters. They aren't modifying the swf, just the HTML you are embedding the swf in.